# C# add primary keys for a table loaded from SQL Server on-the-fly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I would like to load data from SQL Server and assign it to a datatable in C# from VS2013.

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable("myName");

tbl.Columns.Add("id1", typeof(Int16));
tbl.Columns.Add("id2", typeof(Int16));
tbl.Columns.Add("id3", typeof(String));
tbl.Columns.Add("id4", typeof(String));
tbl.Columns.Add("v1", typeof(Int16));
tbl.Columns.Add("v2", typeof(Int16));

tbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { tbl.Columns["id1"],
                                    tbl.Columns["id2"],
                                    tbl.Columns["id3"],
                                    tbl.Columns["id4"] };
```

But, after `tbl` was assigned by the data loaded from SQL Server, there is no primary key in `tbl`.

The table in SQL Server has no primary key.

How to add composite primary key for a table loaded from SQl Server on-the-fly? 
If it is impossible, how to assure that the primary key is set up correctly?

Comment: Define them after loading data from the db

Comment: What method do you use to load data? For example with fill method everything works fine. Also you should check MissingSchemaAction property